# vba code to load text file into ms access table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

[file data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjRiV.png) I need to import a text file data into an Access table. Below is my VBA code

```
DoCmd.TransferText transfertype:=acImportDelim, _
  TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
  SpecificationName:="Generic", _
  FileName:="C:\Users\Documents\Rawfile.txt", _
  hasfieldnames:=False
```

Data is loading into table. 
But when column headers/names order changes in raw file then this TransferText loading data into table as per column headers/names order specified in 'SpecificationName' and doesn't cross check column names in file, resulting the one column data loading into another column in table.

Is there any alternate solution while loading data it should check column names and load data into correct column headers/names ?

Note: column header names doesn't change in file but only column header order may changes in raw file.

Comment: Why the SQL tag? I see no SQL there.

Comment: Yes, no sql in above code. But sql works in ms access. i also tried below query                                
      SELECT * INTO [temp]  FROM [Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;Database=C:\Users\Documents\VBA].Rawfile.txt

Comment: I did not see @Srihari comment before answering - this was what I was thinking would work better.

Comment: but  blank records inserted into table when i tried above query  .

Comment: but "blank records" or are the columns not coming in correctly?  A select * will fail if the input file is missing a column, but I usually want it to fail if something changes (that way).

Comment: even file column names are not coming into table and two columns ypf and f2  are being created. in the table

Comment: Let's stop guessing. Please share a few rows of actual text file.

Comment: text file is tab-delimited (a excel was converted into text file using another macro, i'm trying to load text file into ms access) , file data image is mentioned in post starting

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue with the import specs before.  They're great for layouts that do not change.  There's a couple alternatives, one is via Access's SQL.

```
'RawFile may have to be renamed as .CSV vs .TXT

DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT ColumnIKnow1, ColumnIKnow2, ColumnIKnow3 INTO TargetTable FROM [Text;DATABASE=C:\Users\Documents\;HDR=Yes].Rawfile.csv"
```

Comment: i tried `DoCmd.RunSQL "select [State Name],[Column name2],Country INTO [temp] FROM [Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;Database=C:\Users\Documents].file.csv;"` But  a promote (promote name is "enter parameter value")  is coming for each column mentioned in above query and asking to enter parameter value for all those columns.

Comment: When you get that prompt, it's referring to something it does not recognize in the source.  Is the column header spelled the same in Rawfile?

Comment: This solution assumes text file is comma-delimited. OP, please share your text data which may have different delimiter.

Comment: If they used some other uncommon type of delimiter, you may have to use a schema.ini (or change delimited to tabdelimited as that's the other most common format).   At the same time, since your original import specification was calling for the same delimited value from the Windows registry.... [I may just be pointing out extra info](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/read-text-file-from-query.1675413/) ;)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, text file is tab-delimited.  i copied the column headers from raw file and pasted in query. `DoCmd.RunSQL "select [State Name],[Column name2],[Country] INTO INTO [temp] FROM [Text;FMT=tabdelimited;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Documents\].File.csv;" ` Still i'm getting a prompt for each column and asking to enter parameter values for the columns. i entered few character for each column prompt and it created a table with all columns (mentioned in query) datatype as binary.

Comment: Odd, let me get this straight, so it works after you provide values for each column initially?  I've seen quirks with the editor before like this.

Comment: No, text/csv file data not copied into table. All rows of column have same value which has been provided in prompt window.   i'm new to schema.ini , let me try schema.ini . please let me know if there are any other better options

Comment: I used schema.ini and  vba code is `Option Compare Database
Sub ImportSchemaTable()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    db.Execute _
    "SELECT * INTO Newtab FROM [Text;FMT=tabDelimited;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=C:\Users\smodepalli\Documents;].[File#txt];", _
    dbFailOnError
    db.TableDefs.Refresh
End Sub
`  (i will mention the schema code and data in next comments)
Now result is new table create with file columns but blank rows  being inserted for all columns and number of blank rows is 30(double the data in file). please let me know is there any error in code

Comment: schema.ini code is`[File.txt]
ColNameHeader=True
Format=FixedLength
MaxScanRows=0
CharacterSet=OEM
Col1="Fiscal Year" Char Width 60
Col2="Currency" Char Width 60
Col3="Month" Char Width 60
Col4="Value" Char Width 50` schema.ini file and data file are in same folder. (raw file data is in next comments)

Comment: text file is tab-delimited (a excel was converted into text file using another macro, i'm trying to load text file into ms access) , file data image is mentioned in post starting

Comment: Another option is to create a linked table in Access, that points to the path of your file.  Then you can try to run the query on this "linked" table.  I've had to do this before, to deal with some of the troubles you're having.